# java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

My java code and MySQL stored procedure are working fine on MySQL version: 5.6.44 and 5.7.11. but when I am trying to execute on MySQL version 5.7.27 then it will be showing the SQLException...

> java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting the transaction

Anyone, please let me know which configuration is required to solve this exception.

Comment: Run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on the server at the time this error occurs. Find the SQL that is being timed out. Correlate which long running query is holding the same locks that your SQL needs. Please provide this details if you have difficulty. The [innodb_log_wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) defaults to 50 seconds. Better solutions can be found with more details.

Comment: Thanks, Yes I have increased the timeout time. but I have used MYSQL server in two places: one is the local machine and the second is the server. Both are the same configuration and the same data. But this Exception occurred the only server not in the local machine. Also, this exception has not occurred every time some time service worked successfully but some time failed due to lock Timeout exception. Is it possible for some different configurations for the MYSQL server for Windows and Linux operating systems?